# eggjs can't find the model defined in the 'app/model' directory

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

The project is based on eggjs(v3) and sequelize(v6.0), and fetch data from mysql. I create a 'user' table and defined the same 'user' model in 'app/model/user.js'. However, in the 'controller/user.js', the code can't find the model. The config of sequelize has already been added in 'plugin.js'.

model/user.js:

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    
 const { STRING, INTEGER, DATE } = app.Sequelize;
 
 const Users = app.model.define('user', {
   id: { type: INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
   name: STRING(30),
   age: INTEGER,
   created_at: DATE,
   updated_at: DATE,
 });

 return Users;
 
};
```

controller/user.js:

```
class UserController extends Controller {
 async index() {
  const ctx = this.ctx;
  ctx.body = await ctx.User.findAll();
 }

}
```

when i request the api, it returns an error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findAll')